# colorbox jquery slideshowstart img instead of text

Tags: jquery, colorbox

For the slideshow, I would like to use icons (.png) representing pause ("||"( and play (">") instead of text. I have the following working (the pause text actually looks quite good):

```
$.colorbox.settings.slideshowStart = ">>";
$.colorbox.settings.slideshowStop = "||";
```

Using the SAMPLE below:

```
 $.colorbox({slideshowStop: function(){ var url = $(this).attr('href'); return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Open In New Window</a>';
```

I tried returning "img src="grafix/btn_pause.png" alt="" /' enclosed in angel brackets and also tried "url(grafix/btn_pause)". If I don't put it in quotes, cbox won't launch; but when I enclose in quotes I get the text string instead of the graphic. I see .text in the .js file, so am thinking  only text is allowed. I know html and css but don't know js.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much simpler to change the buttons by targeting them in your CSS - colorbox normally comes with stylesheets you can customise to meet your needs.

Comment: Sean, thank you. My challenge is that there are no buttons to target (I examined the CSS). Next and Prev are there; but not Start or Stop.  (and I believe the jquery is forcing any alternative to text via .text). I tried, as Jack suggested below, putting the img tag in quotes; but that returns/displays the actual text of the tag (no tthe tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the current text with HTML:

`$.colorbox.settings.slideshowStart = "<img src='start.png'/>";`

However, my choice would to be to do with Sean suggested.

Comment: Jack, thank you. When I try this (and I did try before my post), the literal text of the tag is displayed, not the graphic. I think the jquery is forcing any content to text via .text. Joe.

Comment: There are only two places in the jquery to change. I changed .text to .html and I get exactly what I wanted (use any button graphic desired, and hyperlink still works), and it preserves the original behavior (plain text still works fine). I don't want to change the author's jquery; I'd rather have the author do that so it is preserved in future versions. Pardon my ignorance but I don't know how to do request a change. Joe

Comment: Doh! You are right, it does format it as text.  I thought it accepted html like the rest of the internationalization options.  It's an oversight on my part.